# Can't Open File to Read on Amazon Lightsail

Tags: nginx, devops, amazon-lightsail

I have an Amazon Lightsail Nginx server installation and am attempting to read from a JSON file on the server.

File permissions are set to 777 and I set my owner to bitnami:daemon but am still unable to read the file.  I will need to write to it as well. What are the correct permissions/ownership that needs to be set to read/write files on Lightsail?

Answer (score 0):

The correct permissions required are bitnami:daemon on the web folder as well as any affected children items.